# Database error on uploading website designed using codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter

I have been working on a cms based website. But now that its time to upload it shows a database error

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 346
```

I have checked my `database.php` file located in `applications/config`

Its contents:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xy.in';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xy_eta';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xy_livefiesta';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I am sure about the database name and the username
BUt not sure about the hostname(thts the same as the first domain that i purchased while buying a shared hosting)
Please help me out in finding the error

Answer (score 0):

**Web services do not allow you to have databases without a strong password.**

You need to login with the administrator privilidge and set a password for the database and also set the password in the config/database.php file too.

Comment: Tried doing that...as in created a new user and password and assigned the same to my database ...n made changes to database.php...still shows same error

Comment: You need to be careful with the `prefix_` that you might need to use in the configurations!

Comment: well my database name includes the prefix....even then i tried adding it in the dbprefix field ...didnt work:(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your hostname is correct? Try changing it to localhost